# How to test a loop with shuffle in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, testing

How to test in Ruby

```
if shuffle
  some_array.shuffle.each { |val| puts "#{val}" }
end
```

Do I need to test shuffle or no since it is a Ruby method? Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that writing unit tests in your code for built-in functionality is a waste of your time.

Comment: All right. So I don't need to test this at all?

Comment: Only write tests for code you can change. If you're using built-in code, or code from someone else, and they have tests written, then rely on their tests to check their code. In other words, like @Phrogz said, writing tests for Ruby's built-in methods, wastes your time since it's already been tested.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No.

You can trust that Ruby will do things correctly. It has a [huge number of tests](https://github.com/ruby/spec) already.

Long answer: Yes.

You shouldn't be testing the `shuffle` method directly, but testing that your code produces the correct results.

Since your code uses `puts` this makes it very annoying to test. If you can write a method that returns values that *can* be printed, that's usually a lot better. When writing code always think about how you can test it.

If you're struggling with that, where the way to test something isn't clear, **write the tests first** and then write code to make them pass.

If it's imperative that your values be shuffled then you'll need to come up with a way of determining if they're sufficiently shuffled. This can be difficult since randomness is a fickle thing. There's a small but non-zero chance that `shuffle` does nothing to your data, that's how randomness works. This probability grows considerably the smaller your list is to the point where it's guaranteed to do nothing with just one element.

So if you can describe *why* the data should be shuffled, and what constitutes a good shuffling, then you can write a test for this.

Here's an example of how to do that:

```
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'

class MyShuffler
  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end

  def processed
    @data.map do |e|
      e.downcase
    end.shuffle
  end
end
```

Now you can use this like this:

```
shuffler = MyShuffler.new(%w[ a b c d e f ])

# Thin presentation layer here where we're just displaying each
# element. Test code for this is not strictly necessary.
shuffler.processed.each do |e|
  puts e
end
```

Now you write test code for the data manipulation in isolation, not the presentation part:

```
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'

class MyShufflerTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_processed
    shuffler = MyShuffler.new(%w[ A B c Dee e f Gee ])

    results = shuffler.processed
    expected = %w[ a b c dee e f gee ]

    assert_equal expected, results.sort
    assert_not_equal expected, results

    counts = Hash.new(0)
    iterations = 100000

    # Keep track of the number of times a particular element appears in
    # the  first entry of the array.
    iterations.times do
      counts[shuffler.processed[0]] += 1
    end

    expected_count = iterations / expected.length

    # The count for any given element should be +/- 5% versus the expected
    # count. The variance generally decreases with a larger number of
    # iterations.
    expected.each do |e|
      assert (counts[e] - expected_count).abs < iterations * 0.05
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: By If you can write a method that returns values that can be printed, do you mean something like this: if shuffle
      shuffle_array(some_array) end, def shuffle_array(some_array)
    some_array.shuffle.each { |val| puts " #{val}" }
  end ? But where do I even start to test this?

Comment: Keep your methods focused on a singular task if possible. This one should be concerned with re-ordering the array and any other associated transformations. Another method should be responsible for displaying the output. Having two simple methods is often better than one method that does two things, each of which is very hard to test in isolation. My advice? Write a test for this method first. Then fix the method to make it testable.

Comment: Testing methods that produce output is often really obnoxious, you have to grab hold of `$stdin` and redirect it, which is messy. If you can keep your display code as simple as possible, that everything up to that point is tested, it's usually easy to exercise your program and verify visually that the output is correct. If there's a defect it's rarely in the display code at that point, it's in the precursor steps. So: Keep your display code *thin* and obvious. Cover the rest with an appropriate level of test code.

Comment: If anyone can give some code examples, that would be great. I am not sure how to test each loop for this case.

Comment: @Michael Added a quick example here about how to test this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not test randomness using unit test. A unit test should call a method and test the returned value (or object state) against an expected value. The problem with testing randomness is that there isn't an expected value for most of the things you'd like to test.

Comment: I think that may be going a bit far. Let's say, for example, that you have a process that generates random variates for the time between events,  which you expect will follow an exponential distribution, and you wish to test a null hypothesis that the mean of that distribution is a given value. That may be necessary and is certainly doable.